# computer suddenly shuts down (win8)

Tags: windows-8, shutdown

I have a problem with a computer. It sometimes shuts down for no reason and I have to unplug the power cord to restart it.

I recently changed the fan to the power supply so I doubt it's overheating now and after installing windows 8 the computer starting shutting down while loading windows. I uninstalled one RAM unit but that didn't help so I tried changing the place in the motherboard of the units of RAM and the computer started working fine. Can a computer shutdown because of bad memory or a malfunctioning motherboard?

Comment: Do you mean you switched RAM slots? You put the RAM chip from slot1 is now in slot2 and vice versa and now your computer works?

Comment: yes that's what i did.. i suspect slot 2 is bad or the ram is malfunctioning alhough i bought the ram 2~3 months ago

Comment: do you get a BSOD (sad face)? Also look into the Eventlog for Kernel 41 entries and follow this KB: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2028504

Comment: no i don't get bsod even though i did get those on another computer after installing ashampoo hdd control but that's another story. the comp just turns off instantly and i'm not currently over there to see the event viewer.

Comment: it turns out the was a kernel 41 error in the critical event log. i bought the propaganda that it is a power supply problem and spent 50$ for a new power supply. However, the problem persisted so i started to think maybe it's a windows problem but the system shutdown even when i was in bois. For some reason i decided to touch the cooler and it was so hot that i almost burnt my hand off..

Comment: i just removed the cooler and cleeaned all the pile of dust installed core temp to look at the cpu temperature and the computer didn't shutdown even though i loaded the cpu with raring files. so the answer seems ram (memory) can't cause the system to shutdown without the blue screen of death.

Answer (score 0):

it turns out there was a kernel 41 error in the critical event log. i bought the propaganda that it is a power supply problem and spent 50$ for a new power supply. However, the problem persisted so i started to think maybe it's a windows problem but the system shutdown even when i was in bois. For some reason i decided to touch the cooler and it was so hot that i almost burnt my hand off..
i just removed the cooler and cleeaned all the pile of dust, installed core temp to look at the cpu temperature and the computer didn't shutdown even though i loaded the cpu with raring files. so the answer seems ram (memory) can't cause the system to shutdown without the blue screen of death (and even then it restarts)
I think i should persue an A+ certificate, it seems there are still things to learn in computer hardware troubleshooting.